# Expo: Audio.requestPermissions in android build

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have troubles having audio permissions to work on android build. It works fine in expo go, but not in android build.
In the given code, the permission for the camera is asked properly, but when accepted the permission for audio shows only for a fraction of a second and return a not granted status.
Once again, it works fine in expo go.
Is there anything i’m doing wrong ? do you have an idea on how to solve this ?
Thanks you very much community !

**SDK Version: 41
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android (samsung A20e)**

```
import {Camera} from 'expo-camera'
import {Audio} from 'expo-av';

export default () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          Camera.requestPermissionsAsync().then((status) => {
            // audio permission request is only shown for half a second in build mode and is automatically denied permission
            Audio.requestPermissionsAsync().then((status) => {
              console.log('ok');
            });
          });
        }}>
        Test
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to have either both or none in your app.json
that was my problem !

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/get-permissions)

```
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const GetPermissions = async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Requesting permissions..');
    const CameraPerm = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (CameraPerm.status === 'granted') {
      console.log('Camera Permission Granted');
    }

    const AudioPerm = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (AudioPerm.status === 'granted') {
      console.log('Audio Permission Granted');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to get permissions', err);
  }
};

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Button title="Get Permissions" onPress={GetPermissions} />
  </View>
);
```

Make sure all the imports are correct

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't change a thing. even worse, it doesn't block subsequent actions.
thanks for your time